# Instigate wake up with TI CC2541 Bluetooth Low Energy RF Module

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

**Is it possible for a BLE server to wake up a client that is in sleep-mode, as opposed to having the client wake itself up periodically and listen for a broadcast?**

This is under the assumption that the client's address is known by the server. In this application, the client should receive an update only a couple of times per day, so it is not desirable for the client to be constantly listening for a broadcast.

***EDIT:***

These two posts ([1](http://e2e.ti.com/support/low_power_rf/f/158/t/98861.aspx), [2](http://e2e.ti.com/support/low_power_rf/f/538/t/232324.aspx)) from TI's forum seems to answer my question. Low-power modes do not use the radio, and this chip does not seem to have Wake-On-Radio (WOR) capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You are right in your edit. If you look up CC254x datasheet, you see they use around 15mA of power while receiving. This is huge number in this context. Meanwhile you can implement some timer which wakes chip up from time to time and see, if anybody is looking for you.